# How to extend Zend_Form prefix path while configuring form through XML (Zend_Config) to load custom form elements?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm loading my Zend_Form from an XML file :

```
<form>    
  <elements>
    <role>
      <type>MyProject_Form_Element_Select_Roles</type>
      <options>
        <label>Role:</label>
        <value></value>
      </options>
    </role>
    <valid>
      <type>submit</type>
      <options>
        <label>Valid</label>
      </options>
    </valid>
  </elements>
</form>
```

Of course the XML below doesn't work since Zend doesn't know how to load my custom field (which is just an extension of Zend_Form_Element_Select), but the line below doesn't work, if anyone can help :

```
<form>
  <elementPrefixPath>
    <prefix>MyProject_Form_Element_Select</prefix>
    <path>MyProject/Form/Element/Select</path>
    <type>element</type>
  </elementPrefixPath>
...
```

I found these config features really cool but finding info or tutorial on them is really tough (I know there's some mapping rule between the Zend_Form objects structure and the expected config file, but I do never found a complete description of it if someone has a link)

Comment: Well when you figure it all out, post it somewhere for the rest of us. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct form XML description :

```
<form>    
  <prefixPath>
    <element>
      <prefix>MyProject_Form_Element_Select</prefix>
      <path>MyProject/Form/Element/Select</path>
    </element>
  </prefixPath>
  <prefixPath>
    <element>
      <prefix>MyLib_Form_Element_Select</prefix>
      <path>MyLib/Form/Element/Select</path>
    </element>
  </prefixPath>


  <elements>
    <role>
      <type>Roles</type>
      <options>
        <label>Role:</label>
        <value></value>
      </options>
    </role>
    <valid>
      <type>submit</type>
      <options>
        <mycustomoption></mycustomoption>
        <label>Valid</label>
      </options>
    </valid>
  </elements>
</form>
```

The custom options will be send inside the $options argument of the constructor of your Element

```
class MyProject_Form_Element_Select_Roles extends Zend_Form_Element_Select
{
    public function __construct($spec, $options = null) {
        //don't forget to call parent !
        //$options is a Zend_Config that should have as a member mycustomptions
    }
}
```